# .NET VSTO Add In for Excel 2007 not loading config. Issue on one machine only!

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

We have a VSTO Add in for Excel 2007.  It works on all the machines in our office except for one.  This happened after MS updates last week.  Basically, the Add-in won't recognize the config file, but only on that specific machine.  We uninstalled/reinstalled the application, then Excel, then the updates without any success.  We then did a full Win 7 reinstall, loaded Excel, then our app, and got the same issue.  We now have him running our app on a VM with XP and it's fine.  No one else in the organization is having this issue.  Not sure what else to do at this point since a full windows reinstall did nothing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Start > Run > RegEdit > Hkey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addin\YourAddInName\

Edit the Manifest key, from:

Manifest="C:\Program Files\\WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"

To:

Manifest="file:///C:\Program Files\\WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"

To make this work in a deployment, right click on Setup Project in Solution Explorer > click View > Registry > and edit the key.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for posting this.  I forgot this was here and I figured that out a long time ago. Hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Are there no differences in configuration (OS, software etc) between that machine and the others on which it is working? This looks like it could be related...

[VSTO 4.0 SP1 will cause a VSTO Addin to not find its config file.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick!  Not sure why it works on the other machines, but adding 'file:///' to the manifest key was all I needed.