# is it possible to use C# to write functionality within an excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have an excel workbook which needs to query data from an HTTP server. Query directly from a remote database isn't an option.

From what I know I can use VB macros to contact the HTTP server and update the cells in the workbook. Is it possible to do this in C#? I don't want to additional burden of deploying an extra application.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could perhaps set up a local database on a local server and have a C# application keep an up-to-date local cache.

Comment: I've got this covered stay tuned...

Comment: @J... - that's not an option.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - looking forward to it!

Comment: @Remou - i don't have a separate C# application. Would preferably want to deploy just the excel file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the VSTO to create a document or application level addin to Excel. Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128771.aspx

Comment: the document level customization mentioned in the link might just be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: if this is exactly what you need, please mark this post as the answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Follow the first couple of [repro steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526118/bug-cant-choose-dates-on-a-datepicker-that-fall-outside-a-floating-vsto-add-in) to create a Visual Studio Tools for Office - Excel Add-In.

*Skip the last step about the calender control.*

> In the Excel AddIn Project > add a Ribbon Bar and Button and you can
>   invoke methods to collect the data via http and refresh the workbook.
>   Everything in VSTO is pretty much the exact same way you would do it
>   in VBA but in C# syntax.

[Extend Your VBA Code With VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163373.aspx)

When it comes to deploying you should use a Setup Project and it will create an MSI. 
If you have a App.Config file be aware when deploying you need to set the setup project to add a registry key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525693/495455

I highly recommend this blog for tips on better VSTO memory management via .Net code: 
http://jake.ginnivan.net/