# is it possible to use an http datasource in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, vba, datasource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to use C# to write functionality within an excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276526/is-it-possible-to-use-c-sharp-to-write-functionality-within-an-excel-workbook)

I have an excel workbook which needs to query data from an HTTP server. Query directly from a remote database isn't an option.

From what I know, I can use the datasource option to sync data with a remote database. Is it possible to do something similar with an HTTP data source? For instance, where the data and whether the data has changed can be expressed through restful URLs for each cell within the scope of the workbook.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you want but you can go to "Data", "External data source" and then select "From web" if that's what you are looking for (captions are approximate, I work on a French version of Excel 2007).

Comment: Meh. Please do not post the same question twice. I answered to this question while others answered the other question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276526/is-it-possible-to-use-c-sharp-to-write-functionality-within-an-excel-workbook

Comment: @Alexadre - This question had a different intent. I wanted to know if I could source data from and HTTP service, whereas the previous one was regarding the language on the platform.